# Issues with google.setOnLoadCallback

Tags: javascript, materialize

I am trying to leverage some google API for RSS feeds but as I merge it with materializeCSS I am struggling to work through some of the issues.

One issue that has me totally stumped is where I'm not able to add any additional functions outside the google.setOnLoadCallback.

You can see my example at:

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/FPC/pen/pgNYyJ)

The code I am trying to get work is

```
        $( ".archive" ).click(function() {
            $(".cloudUP",this).toggle()
            $(".cloudDone", this).toggle()
        });
```

Which I currently have nested in a loop but doesn't work on the very first collapsible.

Any help is appreciated.